# Firebase Functions iOS Returns Error Not Found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have built and deployed the default 'Hello World' firebase functions, however when I try and call it the error message is 'NOT FOUND'. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Swift Code

```
func cloudRequest(){
    functions.httpsCallable("testFunction").call("") {(result, error) in
        if let error = error as? NSError{
            switch FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
            case .internal:
                print("Internal error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            default:
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        print("Running result condition")
        if error == nil{
            print(result?.data)
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the function deployed in GCP eu west 2 is

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code for your Cloud Function too? While you may have copy/pasted it from somewhere, we'll need to see it to be able to help troubleshooting.

Comment: It seems that you have only added the code to call the function, but further input is needed. As Frank requested, could you attach the function's code? It would also be interesting to see the full error message, how you initialized the `functions` object and what region is hosting your Firebase Function.

Answer (score 2):

1. check whether the function name is correct
2. To call a function running in any location other than the default `us-central1`, you must set the appropriate value at initialization. For example, on Android you would initialize with getInstance(FirebaseApp app, String region).

Ex, lets assume `europe-west3` where your function deployed; to call this function

```js
 functions('europe-west3').httpsCallable('testFunction')(/* ... */)
```

Useful ref:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#initialize_the_client_sdk

Answer (score 0):

As per the updated code, it seems that the target Firebase Function is called `helloWorld`, not `testFunction`. Moreover, it is located in region `europe-west2`. Actually, it also seems like you are using Cloud Functions instead of Firebase Functions.

Notice that a Firebase project has a GCP counterpart, therefore a Firebase Function appears in both projects but a GCP project does not necessarily have a Firebase project linked to it. You will find more information on this in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#firebase-cloud-relationship).

If you intend to call the Cloud Function from iOS, I suggest you move to Firebase Functions, where you will be able to use the Firebase SDK to trigger the function (what you intended to do).

### Firebase library

Use [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function) to learn how to properly write a Firebase Functions and how to deploy it. You should have something like this:

```js
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.helloWorld = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
});
```

Notice that the region is specified when creating the function, otherwise it would be created in `us-central1`.

After that, it will be possible to reach the function using Firebase from you iOS app.

```swift
lazy var functions = Functions.functions(region:"europe-west2")

functions.httpsCallable("helloWorld").call() { (result, error) in
    // code
}
```

This method forces you to deploy a Firebase Function on a Firebase project, it does not work on a GCP-only project.

### HTTP Trigger

If you intend to keep using GCP, you can access your deployed functions using their [HTTP trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http#triggering_the_function). In this case it would be something like the following but with the correct project ID:

```sh
https://europe-west2-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld
```

This method also works using a [Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).